Simple Bank Management System
This is my 2nd C++ project, so I created a bank management system. This was particularly hard because I had to understand OOP. I still don't fully get it, but I'm sure I'll improve as I do more projects. Please feel free to give me feedback on what I could do to improve the project as well as tips on better practices.
Here is the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class BankAccount {
  private:
    double balance;
  public:
    string accountName;
    // Constructor to initialize balance
    BankAccount(double initial_balance) {
      if(initial_balance >=0) {
        balance = initial_balance;
      } else {
        balance = 0;
        cout << "Initial balance cannot be negative. Setting balance to 0." << endl;
      }
    }

    // Method to deposit money
    void deposit(double amount) {
      if (amount > 0) {
        balance += amount;
        cout << "Deposit $" << amount << ". Your Balance is $" << balance << "." << endl;
      } else {
        cout << "Deposit amount must be positive." << endl;
      }
    }

    // Method to withdraw money
    void withdraw(double amount) {
      if (amount > 0) {
        if (amount <= balance) {
          balance -= amount;
          cout << "Withdraw $" << amount << ". Your Balance is $" << balance << "." << endl;
        } else {
          cout << "Insuffient balance. Failed to withdraw." << endl;
        }
      } else {
        cout << "Withdraw amount must be positive." << endl;
      }
    }

    // Method to check balance
    double getBalance() const {
      return balance;
    }

};

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int account_No = rand() % 10000000000 + 1000000000; // Generates some random numbers
  int account_Options;
  double amount;
  BankAccount user1(0);
  // Welcome message and Input for Name
  cout << "Welcome to Simple Bank \n"
          "What is your first name? \n";
  cin >> user1.accountName;
  // Account Details section
  cout << "\nHello " << user1.accountName << ", these are your Bank details: \n";
  cout << "\nAccount Name: " << user1.accountName << endl;
  cout << "Account Number: " << account_No << endl;
  // Account Applicable Options

  while (true) 
  { 
    cout << "How would you like to procceed?\n" << endl;
      cout << "1.Deposit\n"
              "2.Withdraw\n"
              "3.Check Balance\n"
              "4.Exit\n";
      cin >> account_Options;

      const int option1= 1, option2 = 2, option3 = 3, option4 = 4;
      switch (account_Options) {
        case option1:
          int deposit;
          cout << "How much would you like to deposit" << endl;
          cin >> amount;
          user1.deposit(amount);
           break;
        case option2:
          int withdraw;
          cout << "How much would you like to withdraw? \n";
          cin >> amount;
          user1.withdraw(amount);
          break;
        case option3:
          cout << "Your current balance is: $" << user1.getBalance() << endl;
          break;
        case option4:
          cout << "Thank you for using Simple Bank!" << endl;
          return 0;
          break;
        default:
          cout << "Invalid Option" << endl;
          break;
  };
  
      }
      return 0;
}


Do not use using namespace std:
I have to emulate namespaces in C by prefixing each function name with libname_, which looks unaesthetic, is prone to conflicts, and makes me type more. C++ offers namespaces, which is a feature, not a nuisance. Treasure what good you have been offered. If you do not want to type std:: before cout and cin, consider doing:
using std::cout; 
using std::cin;

instead of importing all the symbols.
See also: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.
Avoid srand() and rand() in C++ code:
C++11 introduced new random number facilities that are in many ways superior to the old rand() based stuff. See: How to generate a random number in C++?.
An int might only have 16 bits:
int account_No = rand() % 10000000000 + 1000000000; // Generates some random numbers

An int is only required to hold values in the range −32768 to 32767. So the above operation can overflow, which would result in undefined behavior. Use a larger type perhaps?
Simplify main():
You can move the calls to std::cout for the welcoming part to a separate function, and the part that is printing all the bank details to a separate function, and the part that is printing all the options to a separate function.
The main infinite loop can be moved to a separate function too. This would make your code modular, more readable, and separate different responsibilities.
return 0 is the default behavior:
The absence of a return statement in main() is equivalent to return 0, which is equivalent to return EXIT_SUCCESS, so you can omit it.
But even if you're going to keep it, consider using EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE instead of magic values. Too often I see people exiting on failure with 0 instead of EXIT_FAILURE.
Hiding the switch's case values does not help readability:
const int option1= 1, option2 = 2, option3 = 3, option4 = 4;
      switch (account_Options) {
        case option1:
          ...
        case option2:
          ...
        case option3:
          ...
        case option4:
          ...
  };

Omit option1-option4 and write 1-4 directly.
Do not flush the output buffer unnecessarily:
cout << "How would you like to procceed?\n" << endl;

std::endl flushes the underlying buffer along with printing a newline, which is neither needed, nor appear to be intended. Replace it with a simple '\n'.
Do not ignore input errors:
cin >> amount;

This can fail. The least you could do is:
std::cin >> amount;

if (!std::cin) {
    std::cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

Use an automatic code-formatter:
You seem to have indented the code manually, which shows from the unaligned braces and indents. Consider using one of clang-format, GNU Indent, Astyle et cetera. It would save your time too.
Error messages go to standard error:
In the case that standard output was redirected to a file or a pipe, the error message would go unseen.
cout << "Deposit amount must be positive." << endl;

should be:
std::cerr << "Deposit amount must be positive.\n";

Same for other error messages.

“The absence of a return statement in main() is equivalent to return EXIT_SUCCESS, which is equivalent to exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) …” No, it is absolutely not equivalent. exit() / std::exit() is a C function; returning x from main() is equivalent to exit(x) in C… not C++. Never use exit() / std::exit() in C++. (Also, the absence of a return statement in main() is not equivalent to return EXIT_SUCCESS;, but rather to return 0;. EXIT_SUCCESS is not necessarily 0.)

Ah yes, I forgot. I did not claim that the value of EXIT_SUCCESS is equivalent to 0, but that return 0 is equivalent to return EXIT_SUCCESS and that 0 and EXIT_SUCCESS both indicate success. "If the value of status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned."

You can teach your text editor/IDE to write stuff like std:: on a keypress, in fact a good one will suggest code options and then something like std::cout<< is just pressing tab (for example). You could also use an enum for your switch statement if you want it to be more descriptive.
